# Parsing basic textual output from PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css

```
var req = function () {
    $.ajax({
       url: "out.php",
       cache: false,
       success: function(html) {
          $("#stuff").empty().append(html);
       },
       complete: function() {
          req();
       }
    });
};

req();
```

This snippet above gets the output in the following format: `0,0`

How can I parse that and have one number placed in the CSS selector top and the other in left?

Answer (score 2):

Well, if I understood your PHP output it is something like `x,y` and you need x to be the CSS attribute top and y the CSS attribute left of an element. In my example, I will call the element which will hold these attributes with the id `elem`.

So here it goes:

```
var css_attr = req.split(",");
$('#elem').css('top', css_attr[0]).css('left', css_attr[1]);
```

If you'd like to do it just in `success` of AJAX call just change `var css_attr` to `var css_attr = html.split(",");` and the rest stays the same.

That should be all. The `split()` function is pretty much equal to PHP's `explode()`.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

```
var css_attr = req.split(",");
$('#elem').css({
  top: css_attr[0]+'px',
  left: css_attr[1]+'px'
});
```